# In Sublime Text, using regex, how do I find all text between a double break and a single break, not including the breaks?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

[image: Desired highlighted sections]

How do I find all text that occurs between double breaks and single breaks, not including the breaks? (See screenshot)

Comment: You could use [`^<br\/><br\/>((?!^<br\/>$)[\s\S])+`](https://regex101.com/r/aN9rS7/1)

Comment: This solution seems to include break tags in the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match only the content between your tags, you can use `\K` with lookaround like

```
(?s)<br/><br/>\s*\K(.*?)(?=\s*<br/>)
```

[image]

Make sure the regex match is enabled in sublime text. You can use  <kbd>Alt + R</kbd>  for enabling the regex option.

**NOTE** :- If you want to find `<br/>br/>` only in starting of string you can use anchor `^` in starting of regex.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and sorry for the screenshot, but i put it there so that people could see clearly what I was after. I'm trying to highlight all the text between the double breaks and single breaks, excluding the breaks themselves.

Comment: @JSON updated the answer..use `(?s)(?<=<br/><br/>)\s*\K(.*?)(?=\s*<br/>)`

Comment: This works for me. In the document I'm working with I also have paragraph text between <br/><br/> and <br/><br/>. Ideally the expression would also exclude the text between double breaks and double breaks. I'm perfectly satisfied with your solution, however, and I only mention this if you'd enjoy refining it. Thanks again.

Comment: @JSON what do you expect output for `<br/><br/>
some dummy text here some dummy text here some dummy text here 
<br/><br/>`?

Comment: <br/><br/> Dummy text should not be selected <br/><br/> Dummy text should be selected <br/> Dummy text should not be selected <br/><br/>  Dummy text should be selected <br/>

Comment: @JSON i think for input `<br/><br/> Dummy text should not be selected <br/><br/>`, `Dummy text should not be selected <br/>` can be correct output

Answer (score 0):

You could go for:

```
^<br\/><br\/>((?:(?!^<br\/>$)[\s\S])+)
```

This uses a [***tempered greedy solution***](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html), see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/aN9rS7/2).
Mind the `multiline` modifier.